# AWS Lambda functions in regulated industries

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-lambda

One of the great advantages of AWS Lambda functions is that we don't have to worry about deploying or managing servers. However in some regulated industries (healthcare, finance, etc) we have to worry about our data and code executing in a shared compute instance.

**With that in mind, what kind of virtualization is used to stand up and execute Lambda functions?**

**Do they use Hyper-V (like EC2 instances)**, which enforces better tenant separation (hypervisor layer firewall is used to separate the physical and logical network interfaces and similar mechanisms are used to separate the physical RAM. Any logical disks presented to the instances are securely scrubbed by the hypervisor once unallocated and customers have the option to encrypt at-rest any data persisted in memory) **OR do they use Docker containers to separate Lambdas?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda uses Docker containers behind the scenes.

If you are wondering if you can use Lambda for healthcare or finance systems you are asking the wrong questions. You need to be familiar with the specific compliance standards you are required to meet, like HIPAA for healthcare and PCI for finance. Then you need to read the compliance related documentation published by Amazon. [This is a good place to start](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/services-in-scope/) For example at this time you are not able to use AWS Lambda to process health data covered by HIPAA.